# Additional filter for (image)fields to filter node display

Tags: entities

I need to display nodes on multiple places. For some fields I have multi values. On every place I'd like to display other values of the field. I'd like to have maybe some checkboxes as filter.

For example:

An multi value image field. 3 places to display these image on the site. For every place a checkbox (area1, area2, area3). When checkbox 1 and 3 are checked, this image is displayed only in area1 and area3. When checkbox 2 and 3 are checked for an image, the image is displayed in area2 and area3.

Does anyone knows a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it quite meets 100% of your requirements, but you might want to take a look at the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module. It lets you customize multiple displays per node type, each of which can be configured to display different fields.